# Number of days between two dates in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

How do you get the number of days between two dates in `Thymeleaf`?

Progress up until now:

```
<span th:text="${#dates.format(#dates.createNow(), 'dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm') - #dates.format(feed.dateCreated, 'dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm')}">Number of Days</span>
```

Any help would be highly appreciable.
Thanks

Comment: Haven't seen support for this directly.  I currently handle this server-side (using Joda or Java 8 API) and just put the result on the page.  Another way could be a static call like `<span th:text="${#utilityClass.getDifferenceInDays(date1, date2)}"/>`.

Comment: Using a utilityClass was an option but i wanted to know if there is any support that Thymeleaf provides for this issue. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, this isn't something that Thymeleaf's utilities support, so it is kind of ugly to do.  I tried this, and it works for me:

```
<span th:with="days=${T(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit).DAYS}, millis=${T(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit).MILLISECONDS}" th:text="${days.convert(#dates.createNow().getTime() - feed.dateCreated.getTime(), millis)}" />
```

Instead of doing all this in thymeleaf, I would probably add a getNumberOfDays() method to the feed object that returns the number of days and handle the diff in there. (Or use something like [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/).)

Comment: your answer totally works but i think using a utility class, like bphilipnyc suggested would make it even better.

Comment: The solution will not work with Thymeleaf 3.1.                                                 
Thymeleaf 3.1 establishes a general restriction on the use of classes from core packages: java.*, javax.*, jakarta.*, jdk.*, org.ietf.jgss.*, org.omg.*, org.w3c.dom.*, org.xml.sax.*, com.sun.* and sun.*.                                                                                          Method/constructor calling is now forbidden for classes in these packages, as well as static references.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I did and it worked !

```
<span class="text-small" th:text="${task.timeEnd.getDate() - task.timeStart.getDate()} + ' Days' "></span>
```

Comment: you will get -28 if you try to find the number of days between 2022-03-31 and 2022-04-03